# IE8 - "object doesn't support this property or method" on minified return statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a function that simply gets the query params of a url from a string. (I use it to tweak the `src` attr on an iframe).

Heres the function:

```
getQueryParameters : function (str) {
    'use strict';

    var params;

    if (!/\?.+/.test(str)) {
        return {};
    }

    params = (str || document.location.search).replace(/(.+\?)/, '');
    params = params.split('&');
    params = params.map(function (param) {
                            param = param.split('=');
                            this[param[0]] = param[1];

                            return this;
                        }.bind({}))[0];
    return params;
}
```

Everything works fine both minified and unmified in all browsers except IE8. In IE8 I get this error:

> object doesn't support this property or method

It points me to the minified code here:

> return/?.+/.test(a)?(b=(a||document.location.search).replace(/(.+?)/,""),b=b.split("&"),b=b.map(function(a){return a=a.split("="),this[a[0]]=a[1],this}.bind({}))[0]):{}}});

Any idea as to why?

A lot of the other SO questions with this error are, like this one, specific. I cant seem to figure it out and I will appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't look like the same code, but in any case `.map()` is not supported in IE8.

Comment: Yeah, its the same code. It took me a min to see it. But you're probably right about `.map()`. I didnt think / know about that. I'm going to look into that and you should post that as an answer.

Comment: map() is the issue. `Array.map()` is introduced in ES5 and IE8 is not ES5 compliant. You can use $.map() in [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) if you still want to use map and support IE8

Comment: Yup. That's what I ended up doing. First to answer gets the checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is you're calling map() on array object but it's introduced in ES5 which IE8 doesn't support. In case you want to use map, try JQuery's [map utility](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/).